# Why parameterized or theories tests are ignored by Github workflows

Tags: github, junit, yaml, workflow, parameterized

I'm running my code in GitHub workflows and all of the tests pass. But tests annotated with Theories or parameterized are ignored. Why?

This is my .yml file

```
name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "ca#5" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Set up JDK 17
  uses: actions/setup-java@v3
  with:
    java-version: '17'
    distribution: 'temurin'
    cache: maven
- name: Build with Maven
  run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml  

- name: Run tests with Maven
  run: mvn -B test --file pom.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite my codes in JUnit 5 with the Jupiter test. My tests were in JUnit 4. It runs in GitHub action.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).